# Sybase ASE: how to print all table rows using cursor?

Tags: sql, sap-ase, cursors

The following code is supposed to print all rows contained in the temporary table #table_A:

```
create table #table_A
    (
     ID                  int          NULL ,
     foo                 int          NULL 
    )

go

insert into #table_A values (1, 2)
insert into #table_A values (2, 3)
go

declare c_table_A cursor                     
    for select *                                    
          from #table_A                      
         order                                      
            by 1                                                                      

open c_table_A                               
  fetch c_table_A                            
  while @@sqlstatus = 0                             
    begin                                           
      print '%1!', c_table_A                 
      fetch c_table_A                        
    end                                             
close c_table_A   


go
```

However, it results in the following error message:

```
DECLARE CURSOR must be the only statement in a query batch.
```

How can I print all rows contained in a (temporary) table?

---

Here's another way of putting my question:

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
open c_table_A                               
  fetch c_table_A into @record_variable                           
  while @@sqlstatus = 0                             
    begin                                           
      print '%1!', @record_variable
      fetch c_table_A into @record_variable                       
    end                                             
close c_table_A
```

Is there a way to declare a variable containing a whole row of a table in sybase?

---

P.S.: just using "select * from ..." doesn't work for me. I need to do some stuff with each of the rows before printing the row. (My question is supposed to focus on the essential part, which is why I didn't go into any further details regarding other things I need to do with each row)

Comment: Put a "go" on its own line before the "open".

Comment: once you add the `go` (per Richard's comment), you then need to fix the `fetch` command namely, you need to fetch the cursor columns into `@variables`, and then you need to supply those `@variables` to the `print` command; but seeing how you can (effectively) accomplish the same thing with a simple `select * from ...` (ie, no need for a cursor, loop or `print`), my main question would be... what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would do "select * from #table_A" (followed by go). You don't need a cursor here.

Comment: I know I could save the columns into variables and then print the variables ... but in my application I'm dealing with a large temporary table composed of several other tables. Saving each column in a variable would be too much trouble.
Therefore I want to save the whole row into one "row-variable"

Comment: @markp see my updated post

Comment: @RichardCrossley see my updated post

Comment: @access_granted see my updated post

Comment: ASE 16 has table variables, though I'm not aware of if/how to print a table variable; not sure what you meant in your comment about `a large temporary table composed of several other tables` ... ???? as to the comment about needing to `do some stuff with each of the rows before printing` ... that's what the `update [where current of <cursor>]` statement is for

Comment: @markp, is there a link for those, I was looking at the "Transact SQL users guide" for ASE 16 and didn't see them mentioned. Thx.

Comment: several sections on table types and table variables, etc [table variables](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b65d6a040c4a4709afd93068071b2a76/16.0.3.7/en-US/4bd244685d7c4daf9efbe4d1980bf508.html)

Comment: ran a test on ASE16 ... while I can create a table variable I cannot `fetch` into said table variable, then again, there would be no need for the whole cursor/fetch process since I can just run `insert @tablevar select <columns> from #table_A`, after which I could run various `update` commands to modify the data in `@tablevar`, and finally run `select * from @tablevar`; then again, skip the table variable (and cursor/fetch) and perform direct updates against `#table_A` followed by `select * from #table_A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.

In a SQL batch, rather than a stored procedure the cursor declaration must be separate from the batch that uses it, hence there needs to be a `go` between the `declare cursor` and the subsequent batch.

There is no way to define a "row variable" in Sybase ASE, sorry. Each column returned into a variable must have a variable declared for it. In the example below @id and @foo are declared as the same types as the columns id and foo in the table. Other RDBMS do have "record data types", but unfortunately not Sybase ASE.

Before committing yourself to using a cursor, which on a large table would be relatively slow, you might be able to perform your other processing in a select statement. If there is conditional logic `case ... when ... then ... else ... end` could prove useful, though calling a stored procedure directly from within a select statement is not possible, you can call a SQL user defined function. That's probably a separate question if you need help.

I've added a `deallocate cursor` statement as well, it's part of the syntax and frees up internal workspaces associated with your connection.

You may want to execute `set nocount on` before running the batch, it removes the sometimes annoying `(1 row affected)` message.

```
set nocount on
go

create table #table_A
    (
     ID                  int          NULL ,
     foo                 int          NULL 
    )
go

insert into #table_A values (1, 2)
insert into #table_A values (2, 3)
go

declare c_table_A cursor                     
    for select *                                    
          from #table_A                      
         order                                      
            by 1                                                                      
go

declare
    @id     int,
    @foo    int

open c_table_A                               
fetch c_table_A into @id, @foo

while @@sqlstatus = 0                             
begin                                           
    print 'id: %1! foo: %2!', @id, @foo
    fetch c_table_A into @id, @foo
end                                             

close c_table_A   
go 

deallocate cursor c_table_A
go
```

Comment: with ASE 16 there *IS* a way to define a row (aka table) variable: [table variable](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b65d6a040c4a4709afd93068071b2a76/16.0.3.7/en-US/4bd244685d7c4daf9efbe4d1980bf508.html), though accessing the table variable is done via normal table-level commands (eg, insert, update, delete)